# How to combine 2 video files and audio file with FFMPEG?

Tags: file, audio, video, ffmpeg, console-application

I am attempting to use ffmpeg exe to combine 2 video files and 1 audio.  I wanted the audio to play over "**inputFile.mp4**" and not over the "**outroFile.mp4**" is this possible?  Currently this is what I have.  But Im not sure if what im doing wrong or what I need to get it right.

```
ffmpeg -i "inputFile.mp4" -i "outroFile.mp4" -i "audioFile.mp3" -threads 4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "outputFile.mp4"
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Does inputfile have its own audio? Do you wish to keep it?

Comment: Yes the input file has its own audio but I would prefer if it wasn't there but if it is its ok I've been trying to figure this out for some time.

Comment: Is the inputfile longer than the audiofle?

Comment: Yep the input file is longer than the audio

Comment: I read some documentation that said it would repeat but not sure if this is the case because haven't had any success.

Comment: Do you want it to repeat?

Comment: Yep that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two steps.

**#1**

```
ffmpeg -i "inputFile.mp4" -stream_loop -1 -i "audioFile.mp3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest inputwithaudio.mp4
```

**#2**

```
ffmpeg -i inputwithaudio.mp4 -i outrofile.mp4 -threads 4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "outputFile.mp4"
```

You'll need a recent version of ffmpeg, preferably 4.0, as there's a bug with stream_loop in earlir versions.